# $0$-Dimensional $k$-varieties in the Grothendieck ring $K_0(V_k)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, galois-theory, grothendieck-rings

Let $k$ be a field, and let $K_0(V_k)$ be the Grothendieck ring of $k$-varieties. Let $K_0(V_k^0)$ be the Grothendieck ring of $0$-dimensional $k$-varieties. I also assume that $k$ is perfect.

(1) I have read that $K_0(V_k^0)$ is generated by the classes $[\mathrm{Spec}(K)]$ with $K$ a finite field extension of $k$.

(2) I have also read that $K_0(V_k^0)$ is the free $\mathbb{Z}$-module generated by *the isomorphism classes of transitive permutation representations of $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{k}/k)$.*

As I am come from far outside Galois theory or cohomology theories, I wondered why both statements are true, and if someone could provide some clear references. What happens if $k$ is not perfect ?

Comment: (1) is easy: a $0$-dimensional scheme is a finite union of points, and $[Z^{\operatorname{red}}] = [Z] \in K_0(\mathbf{Var}_k)$ for any $k$-scheme $Z$. Since isomorphism classes of finite transitive $\operatorname{Gal}(\bar k/k)$-sets is the same thing as finite separable field extensions, at least this shows it's generated by such. I'm not sure why there are no relations.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn : "Since isomorphism classes of finite transitive Gal(¯/)-sets is the same thing as finite separable field extensions" -- could you explain this in more detail ? (Thanks !!) -- THC

Comment: This is Galois theory. To a separable field extension $k \to \ell$, associate the set $\operatorname{Hom}_k(\ell, \bar k)$, which has a natural Galois action by postcomposition. Conversely, a finite transitive $\operatorname{Gal}(\bar k/k)$-set is of the form $G/H$ for some closed subgroup $H \subseteq G = \operatorname{Gal}(\bar k/k)$, so take $\ell = (\bar k)^H$. Galois theory says that these constructions are inverses.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn : does $(\overline{k})^H$ denote the fixed elements subfield in $\overline{k}$, of $H$ ?

Comment: In characteristic zero, classes of fields are linearly independent by the Larsen-Lunts theorem, as in the answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354718/field-extensions-in-grothendieck-rings/354805#354805